# how to add new users to database

Tags: php, database, wamp

i have a login page and a register page, and i want that i can communicate with my database. i have a data base from wamp(phpmyadmin). how do i connect so that i can add new user in my database. 
this is what is have:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <lang ="nl">
  <title>Nieuw account</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nieuwaccountstyle.css">
</head>
<body>
  <center>
  <div id="lijn">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Nieuw account aanmaken</b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><br>Gebruikersnaam:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="gebruikersnaam"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wachtwoord:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="wachtwoord"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="email" name="email"><br></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="aanmaken" value="Aanmaken"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
</body>
```

Comment: Just google it you will get codes then if you have any doubt ask here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you have to learn,

- Form action.
- Methods to Get Data from HTML Form to PHP.
- Creating Database and table in php.
- Database connectivity in php.
- Running Mysql Queries in php & CRUD operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest that you learn php first or just download a book about Php and my MySQL that the only way you will understand it cause writing a code for you it wont make sense.